# What is the best use case of a regular expression (TripleByte question)?

Tags: regular-expressions

I have lots of experience with regexes. I just want to make sense of this. Am I missing something here. Which one of these would you rather **validate** with a regex? [Question reads](https://twitter.com/TheEvanCarroll/status/1203440763834654720),

> Which of the following is the best use case for a regular express?
>
> Select the correct answer:
>
> - Validate an IP address
> - Validate a SQL query
> - Validate JSON text
> - Validate HTML

I'm not sure it would be easy to validate any of these with a regex.

1. Would have to include 32 bit integers, and things like 8.1, and all kinds of other edge cases
2. Is incredibly complex and even if were just talking about a spec you'd be talking about thousands of SLOC inside of the regex for the grammer.
3. While somewhat doable, would require a recursive regex
4. Could include one of five versions, potentially XML schemas, SGML dtds and all kinds of absurd stuff.

Comment: Any sequence of 1 to 3 digits, dot, 1 to 3 digits, dot, 1 to 3 digits, dot, 1 to 3 digits is probably considered a valid IP address. The others require a dedicated parser. So the first one would be the right answer.

Comment: @MartinMaat really, try 394.201.203.403? And just telling one potential IP address isn't a validator in any useful sense. A regex can also check for `<!doctype html><title>.</title>` which is a valid HTML5 document.

Comment: @Evan I am just giving you the likely mind set of the questioneer. Now that I read your post again and followed the link I am not so sure anymore this is a question you got asked and are interested to see answered. If you want to do pop quizzes this is not the place.

Comment: @MartinMaat I've already chosen an answer .... I just found your comment to be factually incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that I wouldn't use a regular expression for any of them, but if I *had* to choose, I would go for the IP address, because the other ones all have a nested structure, and are therefore not well-suited for regular expressions, which is what I think they are trying to get at.

Comment: I would go with that. It's a useful distinction but I guess if that's what they're getting at it would be better to ask which one was not recursive.